# How do I transfer all the contents of a file based on a criteria to another folder?

Tags: finder

[image]

I have multiple folders i.e., Fold1_part1 which have 6 subdirectories in them. In each of them has 3 folders full of images labelled either 0,5,10. I am trying to move them to another folder which will hold all the images for each category(3 folders which are 0, 5 or 10).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  What have you tried already that didn't work (so people don't recommend steps that you've already done)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Terminal

```
mkdir -p path/to/target/{0,5,10}
cd path/to/Frames
mv */*/0/* path/to/target/0/
mv */*/5/* path/to/target/5/
mv */*/10/* path/to/target/10/
```

PS: Use `mv -i` to get prompted in case of identically named files.

Comment: Wow such a simple and easy solution did not know it was possible.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by writing a python script. Was just looking to see if Finder had any builtin functionality to do it.

EDIT: Added in the code!

```
import shutil
import os 
import time 
import sys
import concurrent.futures

path_HDD = "/Volumes/HDD/frames/"
path_10 = "/Volumes/HDD/frames_final/10"
path_0 = "/Volumes/HDD/frames_final/0"
path_5 = "/Volumes/HDD/frames_final/5"

def move(path):
    for root, files, directory in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
            if(len(root) == 36 or len(root) == 37):
                if(len(root) == 36 and int(root[-1]) == 0):
                    for r, d, f in os.walk(root, topdown=False):
                        for fi in f:
                            file_path = os.path.join(r, fi)
                            try:
                                shutil.copy(file_path, path_0)
                            except OSError as error:
                                print(error)
                                break
                elif(len(root) == 36 and int(root[-1]) == 5):
                    for r, d, f in os.walk(root, topdown=False):
                        for fi in f:
                            file_path = os.path.join(r, fi)
                            try:
                                shutil.copy(file_path, path_5)
                            except OSError as error:
                                print(error)
                                break
                elif(len(root) == 37 and int(root[-2:]) == 10):
                    for r, d, f in os.walk(root, topdown=False):
                        for fi in f:
                            file_path = os.path.join(r, fi)
                            try:
                                shutil.copy(file_path, path_10)
                            except OSError as error:
                                print(error)
                                break
    print("DONE")
    sys.exit(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try :
        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor():
            move(path_HDD)
    except OSError as error:
        print(error)
```